# Is it possible to use a task for formatting on save in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I use a custom code formatter ([`forge fmt`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/formatter#int_types)) to format my Solidity code, but this formatter is not part of any VSCode extension.

I would like to use it to format on save. What I typically do to enable format on save in VSCode is add the following settings (in this example, I am using the [Prettier VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)):

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[solidity]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" 
  }
```

The trouble is that the `defaultFormatter` setting expects the name of an extension, but there isn't any bespoke VSCode extension for my formatter at the moment.

Would it be possible to instead use a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) for formatting on save?

**Update**: it looks like there is actually an [extension](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity) that has support for my custom formatter. Still, I wish to keep my question open, because I will probably bump into this problem again in the future.